# PHP/MYSQL - Drop database using prepared statement

Tags: php, pdo, drop-database

I would like to drop a database using PDO.

This approach was the best one to me

```
function delete_db($database)
{
  $statement = $my_pdo_obj->prepare("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS :database");
  $statement->bindParam(":database", $database);
  $statement->execute();
}
```

But unfortunately, I got a PDOException saying that there is a syntax error near my binded value ($database) :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1'

So I tried to perform the query as follow

```
function delete_db($database)
{
  $statement = $my_pdo_obj->exec("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS " . $database);
}
```

And it works.

I was wondering why the prepared statement was not working and also, if the second query was secured.

Thanks in advance for your ideas !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use binding values for table names, database names etc.

http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php#111977

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! What about the second one, should I keep it ?

Comment: If you need do this from your application, why not. But don't forget protect from SQL injections